# Java javassist method calling

Tags: java, methods, code-injection, javassist, javaagents

So I'm using java agent with javassist for purpose of injecting some small monitoring related code to different methods in different classes.

My java agent code:

```
public class ConverterAgent implements ClassFileTransformer {

public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation){
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> Intializing Java agent <<<<<<<<<<");
    ConverterAgent transformer = new ConverterAgent();
    instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer);

}

public static void agentmain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation){
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> Intializing Java agent <<<<<<<<<<");
    ConverterAgent transformer=new ConverterAgent();
    instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer); 
}


@Override
public byte[] transform(final ClassLoader loader, 
        String className, 
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined, 
        ProtectionDomain protectionDoman, 
        byte[] classFileBuffer)
                throws IllegalClassFormatException {



//javassist code goes here


return classFileBuffer;

}

}
```

And my javassist injections look like this:

```
if ("className1".equals(className)){

//code

}


 if ("className2".equals(className)){

//same code as in first class

}


if ("className3".equals(className)){

//same code as in first and second class

}
```

So I'm injecting the same exact code multiple times, I want to optimize my process and call a method for every injection so I don't have to copy same code all over and over again. But here's where I hit my problem, what Method Type am I supposed to use and what arguments does it need besides Class and Method names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Into you transform method you are taking the class bytecode and then returning the "new" class bytecode with your modifications.

This means that for sure what you are going to **return is the byte[]** containing the information needed into the transform method.

So your method should be something like that:

```
public class DynamicTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class classBeingRedefined,
    ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;

        // into the transformer will arrive every class loaded so you filter 
        // to match only what you need
        if (className.equals("com/full/path/to/be/instrumented/className1") ||
            className.equals("com/full/path/to/be/instrumented/className2") ||
            className.equals("com/full/path/to/be/instrumented/className3") ) {

            byteCode = myMethodThatTransform(className, byteCode);
        }

        return byteCode;
    }


    public byte[] myMethodThatTransform(String className, byte[] byteCode){\
        try {
            // retrive default Javassist class pool
            ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
            // get from the class pool our class with this qualified name
            CtClass cc = cp.get(className);
            // get all the methods of the retrieved class
            CtMethod[] methods = cc.getDeclaredMethods()
            for(CtMethod meth : methods) {
                // The instrumentation code to be returned and injected
                final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String name = meth.getName();
                // just print into the buffer a log for example
                buffer.append("System.out.println(\"Method " + name + " executed\" );");
                meth.insertBefore(buffer.toString())
            }
            // create the byteclode of the class
            byteCode = cc.toBytecode();
            // remove the CtClass from the ClassPool
            cc.detach();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be much more efficient if you used a map rather than multiple equals checks separated by ||

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem, I'm sure somebody else will also find your code very useful.